# How to convert language code to locale name?

Tags: django, locale

How to convert language code to locale name in Django?

For example:

- `zh-cn` to `zh_CN`
- `zh-Hans` to `zh_Hans`

Answer (score 2):

```py
from django.utils.translation import to_locale
from django.conf import settings

print to_locale(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```